# Error when populating a database table while installing a module

Tags: jdatabase, custom-module, sql, jinstaller

I am using the following code for creating tables in my `.sql` file as part of a module.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `#__gruposlocales` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `latitude` float(10,6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255.000000',
    `longitude` float(10,6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '255.000000',

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

INSERT INTO `#__gruposlocales` (`id`, `latitude`, `longitude`) SELECT userid, latitude, longitude FROM `#__community_users`;
INSERT INTO `#__gruposlocales` (`name`) SELECT name FROM `#__community_groups` WHERE id=ownerid;
```

However, when I try to install the module, I get this error:

> JInstaller: :Install: Error SQL Unknown column 'latitude' in 'field list'
>   Extension Install: SQL error processing query: DB function failed with error number 1054 
>   Unknown column 'latitude' in 'field list'
>   SQL =
>   `` INSERT INTO `#__gruposlocales` (`id`, `latitude`, `longitude`) SELECT userid, latitude, longitude FROM `#__community_users`; ``

Is my code wrong? Could anybody help to fix this, please?

Comment: The table you select from has a latitude field?

Comment: Yes, @SvenBluege, one of the table I select from has the following fields: userid, latitude, and longitude. The code works perfectly inside of phpmyAdmin, creating the requested table from those two other tables.

Comment: Has your database user more than one joomla installation? Did you use the right replacement for #__ while running it in phpmyadmin? Another Idea: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=1689

Comment: Thank you, Sven. Yes, there a more than one Joomla installation and yes I used the #_jos fashion. I read the article you kindly pointed me out. I have followed every suggestion but I get the same error. As for the grave accents instead of straight quote marks, I have this code that works well with no complains:

INSERT INTO `#__helloworld` (`hello`, `lang`) VALUES ('Hello World', 'en-GB');
INSERT INTO `#__helloworld` (`hello`, `lang`) VALUES ('Hola Mundo', 'es-ES');
INSERT INTO `#__helloworld` (`hello`, `lang`) VALUES ('Bonjour tout le monde', 'fr-FR');

Comment: The grave accents are not visible and I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Ok, I figured out something. There is a table called #__gruposlocales in my database (not #_jos...). If I eliminate it, it comes back. Inside of it, there are no columns or rows, That is probably why, the error says "unknown column latitude"

Comment: Does anybody know why this is happening, please?

Comment: @Pable Castelo how do you execute that SQL? You're using Joomla query stuff, right? #__ is a placeholder for the table prefix. I'm sure there is no #_jos....

Comment: Sorry, sorry. My explanations have been confusing. There is not a #_jos syntax. I meant jos_ syntax. My fault. I am creating a module so I am using the code that I initially posted inside of a mod_moduleXX.php with the #__ convention as you could see. Before, I was following a tutorial which uses #__helloworld which successfully generates a josok_helloworld table inside of Joomla. For some reason, something is creating a #_gruposlocales among the other josok_ tables. If I delete it, something makes it appear again.

Comment: This is a pic, so you can see what I mean https://lab.latinface.com/images/photos/567/1/gruposlocales.jpg

Comment: Please double check your code. Is the SQL-files used by the Joomla installer?

Comment: I figured it out! First, I was right: the pre-existent table with no columns was stopping me to install my module and was responsible for the error. I could not delete it because the icon "Drop" doesn't work on my server. I used "With selected:" select "Drop" option and it worked. Once the table was deleted, the module was installed with no errors. And, the code was good and it did what it was thought to do. Thank you @SvenBluege for all your help and interest.

Comment: I added the answer. Feel free to approve it :)

Answer (score 1):

Your database contained more than one Joomla table set. The install script got confused by that.

Comment: I think for the green tick, this answer needs a bit more context from the string of comments.  Please write a comprehensive answer that can stand alone in case comments are deleted.